# Change the button label in MUI_WELCOMEPAGE with NSIS

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

I want to change the button label on the installers welcome page, that says "Install".

Since it's more of a downloader (downloading the actual installerfile), the "install" button might be confusing for customers.

I searched the web, but didn't really find something.
I use MUI (**not** MUI2!)

I hope you guys have an idea, it would be pretty cool to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I finally found the solution:

```
InstallButtonText "String"
```

Comment: If you think it's the answer so accept it, doesn't matter it's your one.